# PHP, объясните основы ООП

Tags: php, ооп

1. Интерфейс в PHP нужен для взаимодействия между двумя классами?
2. Абстрактный класс — это класс, реализующий хотя бы один абстрактный метод, и в каких случаях используется, а в каких не нужно?
3. Статическое свойство доступно во всех экземплярах классов?
4. Статический метод работает только со статическими свойствами и может вызываться без создания нового экземпляра класса?

Comment: Я думаю, что лучше этот вопрос разбить на 4

Comment: Уже разобрался.

Comment: Да?.. ну тогда напишите ответ - кому-нибудь еще понадобится

Answer (score 2):

1. Интерфейс нужен для декларации набора публичных свойств и методов. А применяться он может где угодно - например, для передачи параметров.
2. Абстрактный класс может быть вообще без методов. К тому же, в классическом ООП абстрактный класс вообще ничего не должен реализовывать, а только определять для наследования. Используется в случае необходимости использования полиморфизма для обработки однородных объектов. Не нужен в случае единичных функций или в случае фиксированных, не расширяемых структур.
3. Статическое свойство принадлежит самому классу и, в зависимости от модификатора доступа, может быть использовано либо только в самом классе (private), только в наследниках (protected) или откуда угодно (public). В отличии от динамических свойств, статическое свойство как бы одно на все объекты данного класса. Динамические свойства хранят значения для каждого объекта свое.
4. Статический метод может использовать объекты, переданные как параметры. Но в принципе - да. Статический метод не может иметь прямой доступ к динамическим свойствам класса без наличия экземпляра этого класса.